# Run concurrent webservice requests using JMeter

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, soap, jmeter

I need to run a performance test on JMeter against a SOAP-based webservice. I have set up the Tests for this. What I want to do is make 5 requests one after another in 1 thread group with a delay of 1 second between the requests for a certain amount of time (ex. 2 hours ...) **BUT** I don't want to wait for the response of one request and then proceed to the next i.e. I want to fire 1 request, wait exact 1 second, fire the second, wait exact 1 second fire the next request etc. and then collect the results after the test has finished. This is a requirement.

My Questions:
1. Does JMeter have any option to accomplish this task?
2. If the answer to the 1st question is yes, how would I accomplish such a task?
3. If the answer to the 1st question is no, is there a substitute for JMeter that can handle such a task?

Thanks,

Comment: I just downloaded gatling. Any suggestions on how this task can be done using Gatling?

Comment: Check this answer. I think this is what you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833188/sending-web-request-and-not-waiting-for-response

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Timer element to your samplers. You can configure the Timer to be constant (1 sec) or even choose the wait time to be drawn from a Normal distribution. Find out more info here: http://2min2code.com/articles/jmeter_intro/constant_timer

Comment: That is what I tried first but it seems timer waits for the response of the last request before it gets activated, which is not quite what I want. I don't care about the response, I want to wait exactly 1 second after the current request was made to fire the next one. If the response took 5 seconds, by using a constant timer of 1 second, the next request will start after 6 seconds

Comment: I believe that what you want to do is to use multiple threads and use a Constant Throughput Timer. Also look into Ultimate Thread Group or Stepping Thread Group (jmeter plugins) and you can also modify the Timeouts (milliseconds) field in every Sampler to make the wait time for every response be very small.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment there is no possibility to configure JMeter to send requests as you described.

However JMeter provides the option to limit JMeter's throughput to 1 request per second. See [How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) for details on how to get this done.